# Telegram Bot PHP Warning while opening a stream

Tags: php, warnings, bots, telegram

I get a negative response from the `file_get_contents` as follows

> Telegram Bot PHP: Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: 400 Bad Request

**Code in Context**

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

$botToken = "249706675:AAGGJtFStHf6zbuQfbAClcGzzlFz75xqFKA";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$updateArray = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$chatId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $updateArray["message"]["text"];

switch($message) {  
    case "/hello":
        sendMessage($chatId, "Hello!");
        break;
    case "/wtf":
        sendMessage($chatId, "I'm personal bot of @TCGroup!");
        break;
    default:
        sendMessage($chatId, "Default");    
}

function sendMessage($chatId, $message) {   
    $url = $GLOBALS["website"]."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
    file_get_contents($url);    
}
```

Comment: Which of the two `file_get_contents`s give an error

Comment: /home/azumauz/public_html/telegrambot/tcguz-functions.php on line 30, second `file_ged_contents` give an error

Comment: it is possible that you forgot the extension to " sendmessage " or is managed by .htaccess ?
you can carve out $url ? maybe you do send through the function mail()

Comment: Are you trying to do request using cURL, or it's impossible?

Comment: I alredy tryed cURL func, but messages from bot don't send me messages :( 
Mail() func not working too

Comment: Works fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try camelCasing your sendMessage in the url. And use cURL extension instead of file_get_contents, as it's more efficent.